# Chrome is not updating to 0.84?

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome say to download and install which I do via the .deb: sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

But nothing changes when I open chrome. Following the chain of symlinks I am pointing to the google-chrome in /opt/google/chrome which is timestamped to a week ago not today when I ran the update.

Should I *uninstall* chrome? Not sure if this will wipe some local config which I would rather not do.

Comment: My Chrome did update recently without need to install anything from a deb file.

Comment: Did you download a new deb file, or installed an old one?

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy google-chrome-stable` and `apt-cache policy | grep chrome` to the question body by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1260346/edit). Mine have just updated from *83.0.4103.116-1* to *84.0.4147.89-1* .

Answer (score 1):

I ended up uninstalling chrome which seemed to be fine but not sure it was needed in the end.

I *think* the issue is actually chrome misreporting a version problem. I downloaded and installed chrome and then went to help -> about chrome and updated the minor version there. The red flag then disappeared after that.